# one of two GPU fans won't spin

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, gpu, fan

There are 2 fans on my AMD Radon HD 7900 and one of them is working fine (spinning permanently). The other one spins for a second when booting the PC but then it stops. I tried setting fan speed manually using AMD software and MSI afterburner, so I'm sure it actually should spin. It's a fan with 4 pins, presumably: +12v, ground, Tach and control/PWM. If I connect only +12v and ground the fan is spinning at full speed. Adding Tach seems to have no effect, but as soon as I connect PWM it stops. If I disconnect PWM again it spins for one second just like when booting. Any ideas how this behavior can be explained? Or what I could try to fix it?

Comment: Replace the fan with a new one. That is what I would do.

Comment: The fan is physically dead. Just purchase a new fan. Not work repairing.